# Containerized NextJS taking long time to respond to request

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js, containers

I've been trying to containerize an extremely basic NextJS application over the last few days. The app works, and I can access it, but it's taking up to 1.14 mins to respond to a basic request to index.js that just includes an H1 Testing element. I've already tried looking around but found nothing.

[Image of the Network Tab from my FireFox dev tools after requesting the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHB9B.png)

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /.

# This line makes sure that no dev dependences are install in a production environment
ARG NODE_ENV
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
        then npm --production=false install; \
        else npm install --only=production ; \
        fi
COPY . ./

ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

My docker-compose.yml (Note: I removed the API and Mongo services, both work correctly and as expected):

```
version: '3'

services:
  dashboard:
    build: ./client/dashboard
    env_file:
      - ./environment/dashboard.env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - api
```

My docker-compose.dev.yml (I run alongside with normal docker-compose. I removed the API and mongo again):

```
version: '3'

services:
  dashboard:
    volumes:
      - ./client/dashboard:/app
    build:
      context: ./client/dashboard
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    command: npm run dev
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=developmet
```

[Next.JS]: My index.js:

```
function IndexPage() {
    return (<div>
        <h1>Hello World Number Seven!</h1>
    </div>)
}

export default IndexPage
```

[Next.JS]: My _app.js

```
import { VechaiProvider } from "@vechaiui/react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (<VechaiProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </VechaiProvider>)
}

export default MyApp
```

[Next.JS] My next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  },
  webpackDevMiddleware: config => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    }
    return config
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Edit: The command I use to run the app is: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d --build`

Comment: What command does your `dev` script run?

Comment: The dev script runs `next dev`